# how to pass the stdin integers and convert them to a binary file using wb and fwrite?

Tags: c

The following program is intended to collect, from standard input, a list of integers and deposit the respective values, in binary, in a file identified by the command line argument. When I compile the code and open `new.bin`, it appears to hold letters, not the binary integer. Can anyone help me find what´s wrong with this code, please?

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int v;

    FILE *f;    
    f = fopen (" new.bin", "wb");

    if (f == NULL){
            printf("Erro ao abrir ficheiro.\n");
            return 2;
    }
    while (scanf("%d", &v)==1){ 
         fwrite(&v, sizeof v  ,1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The filename has a space at the front; that's not formally wrong, but it is eccentric and makes handling the filename harder.  The code should work fine.  How are you inspecting the output?  What values did you specify as inputs?  What did you get as output?  Maybe you should show a sample input file with say half-a-dozen integers in it, and the output from `xxd -g 1 " new.bin"` (an example of why the leading blank is a nuisance) from running your program on  the data file.

Comment: Side notes: (1) don't pass string literals to `fopen()`; it makes it hard to report the file name in the error message — always use a variable: `char filename[] = "new.bin"; f = open(filename, "wb"); …`.  (2) Report errors on standard error, not standard output: `fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file %s for writing\n", filename);`.  You did include the trailing newline — that's good (important). (3) If you aren't going to use the command line arguments, use `int main(void)` rather than `int main(int argc, char **argv)` — it avoids warnings about unused variables when your compiler is set fussy.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Depending on how you "open" it, it may be in hexadecimal, which includes 1-9, A-F in its numbering system.

Comment: Hi everyone! Input: 5 c ;;;;output(in out.bin):ENQ